# "In the event of rain, the parade is canceled." Is it correct?

Tags: conditionals, imperatives, conditional-future

I have found a conditional sentence "In the event of rain, the parade is canceled." on page http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+event+of

I have thought that main clause of such conditional sentence should contain future or imperative mood. For example:

- In case of an emergency, push this button.
- In the event of a fire, alarms will sound.

But in this sentence main clause contains present. Is it correct?

Is correct similar sentence with future:
"In the event of rain, the parade will be canceled."?

What the difference between these two sentences if both correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.  *In the event of* carries the meaning of "if" and should not be followed by the present tense.  The example is wrong.